# JQDateRangeSlider get slider interval only for one day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the JQDateRangeSlider for the first time and I use it as a time slider: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/149/)

The beggining time interval is:

```
min2 = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 00, 00, 00),
max2 = new Date(2016, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);
```

that display hours among 11 months, I guess, instead of only one day like today, starting from 00:00 to 23.00. The time values can be changed by pressing the Min and Max buttons that gets the current date and time, or from another day, and changes bounds to the slider. If the changed value is between min2 and max2 the slider updates ok but if it doesn't, the slider does not look like it supposed to.

Is there any way to have by default values only for one day (starting with 00:00 and ending with 23:59), and also to be able to change min and max on button click without broken the slider even if the bounded day is different than the first/default day?